# maven error message "1 required artifact is missing"

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

Now, this is my pom(.xml) configuration:

```
<build>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/resources/development</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <attach>true</attach>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>mypackage.MyMainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <!-- configure the plugin here -->
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration></configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--
        Plugin that can be configured to prevent deployment of artifact to the
        maven2 repository.
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vantage.iseek.content</groupId>
        <artifactId>iseek-content-publisher-ds</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.vantage.iseek.content</groupId>
        <artifactId>iseek-content-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
        <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <scope>testing</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Route commons over slf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Use log4j as binding -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <url>http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/groups/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <url>http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/groups/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>

<distributionManagement>

    <!-- use the following if you ARE NOT deploying a snapshot version. -->
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Vantage Nexus Release Repository</name>
        <url>
            http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/repositories/vantage-release
        </url>
    </repository>

    <!-- use the following if you ARE deploying a snapshot version. -->
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshot</id>
        <name>Vantage Nexus Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>
            http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/repositories/vantage-snapshot
        </url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>

</distributionManagement>

<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>env-development</id>
        <properties>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>development</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

`

When I run : `mvn clean assembly:single` It gives the following error message:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project iseek-content-fetcher-fb: Failed to create assembly: Failed to resolve dependencies for project: com.vantage.iseek.content:iseek-content-fetcher-fb:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Missing:`

`[ERROR] ----------`

`[ERROR] 1) com.vantage.iseek.content:iseek-content-publisher-ds:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

`[ERROR]`

`[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.`

`[ERROR]`

`[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:`

`[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.vantage.iseek.content -DartifactId=iseek-content-publisher-ds -Dversion=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file`

`[ERROR]`

`[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:`

`[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.vantage.iseek.content -DartifactId=iseek-content-publisher-ds -Dversion=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]`

`[ERROR]`

`[ERROR] Path to dependency:`

`[ERROR] 1) com.vantage.iseek.content:iseek-content-fetcher-fb:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

`[ERROR] 2) com.vantage.iseek.content:iseek-content-publisher-ds:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

`[ERROR]`

`[ERROR] ----------`

`[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.`

`[ERROR]`

`[ERROR] for artifact:`

`[ERROR] com.vantage.iseek.content:iseek-content-fetcher-fb:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

`[ERROR]`

`[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:`

`[ERROR] nexus (http://maven2.vantage.com:8080/repo/content/groups/public, releases=true, snapshots=false),`

`[ERROR] central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)`

But in the target directory I always find iseek-content-fetcher-fb-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar when I run `mvn install`
Could somebody please point what I'm missing?

Comment: Maven cannot find this artifact in your local repository, which is `~/.m2/`.

Comment: It seems that library isn't in your repositories (remote and local), you can install it manually following the instructions in the error log.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov: Thanks . But how can I point to that directory?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have one maven-Projekt " iseek-content-fetcher-fb" that you are working on and which your reference via dependency in another local project.

Maven do not scan your projects in eclipse target folder. It is only aware of maven-artifacts in your local-repository "~/.m2" or remote-repository like http://mvnrepository.com/.

You have to compile and install your maven project to local repository with: mvn install

```
install - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
```